# PDF export missing a sheet in some countries

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, acrobat

I know there are a load of Excel-to-PDF related questions but I think I've come across a unique case.

I'm using a standard line to export all visible sheets from a workbook, via Access:

```
xlWb.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=0, Filename:=fp, Quality:=0, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
   IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

There are various reasons I'm not using an array of sheet names.

I work for a multi-national. In Europe and Asia Pacific everything works OK but in Africa and the Middle East one worksheet is consistently missing from the PDF export.

Things I've checked / tried:

- There is a used and filled range
- Page breaks & print area are appropriate
- Page orientation is the same as other sheets
- Page setup DPI setting is the same as other sheets
- Early vs late binding of Excel
- Non VBA: manually exporting the workbook as PDF
- Tested with multiple users in region

It's always the exact same sheet, which happens to be the last **visible** sheet in the workbook.

**Update** - additional tests

- Extended the print area to take up most of a page
- Reset the page setup to defaults / auto (breaks, print area, scale etc)
- Added a sheet after the sheet in question (neither sheet printed)
- Copied the sheet after itself (neither printed)
- Saved the file before printing PDF
- Deleted all hidden sheets

What did work was to move the sheet, however the sheet that was now in the same place (last in the file) did not get printed instead.

Comment: does it get exported if you add an empty one after that last one? Does it happen to any other worksheet you move into that position? Or is it the same worksheet even if it is in another position. Hard to tell what's going on, any possibility that there is intefering code before that line? Any events? Did the non VBA manually export work?

Comment: Good questions. Those offices are closed for the day now, I'll try the sheet order & extra sheet tomorrow and report back. The non-vba export also misses that sheet so I'm guessing its some sort of page setup issue rather than code. Odd thing for me is that tts region specific, maybe a clue? There are no events in the Excel file and no timers or other events in the DB which would interrupt execution.

Comment: *"The non-vba export also misses that sheet"* that actually means it is very likely no code involved. Are you sure it is regional or is it just a coincidence like all in one region have a special version of office installed. Like one region have the 365 the others have the 2019. Just make sure you don't run into a trap with the regions. In the end it might be that it is a bug in a localization of office but I think this is very unlikely too. • Actually next step to find out would be: Is it the position of the sheet or a specific sheet. Then further investigations from that step.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I've updated the post with some additional info. Still no joy. Maybe corruption? The workbook has been around in one form or another for a few years. Still only one region of the world it fails in though, MEA.

Comment: If you suspect a corrupted file you can try to save it in the binary format `xlsb` and then back to `xlsm`. This can help to get rid of corruption as the file needs to be converted. If that doesn't help you can try with a fresh workbook and see if you can produce the same issue. Rebuilding the file from scratch can remove corruptions too. • Note that for big and relevant files I only use `xlsb` because it is smaller and less likely to corrupt. With `xlsm` and `xslx` I had many files corrupted. Never happened with `xlsb`. Looks to be much more stable.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Found the problem & posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that shrinking the columns a few points to fit the page further within the page margins did the trick. Although Excel print previewed the sheet fine I guess Acrobat saw it as over-running the print margins and excluded it from the export.

Another takeaway is that when converting to PDF page setup settings in one region of the world will not necessarily work as expected in other regions.

Comment: Actually different font versions (of the same font eg Arial) installed on different computers can change the size of the cells too. We had this issue once Microsoft broke some font with a Windows update (and fixed it in the next update). Made a huge mess because nothing fitted on the page as planned just because the font version changed. • Thx for posting the answer, as this solution came pretty unexpected it might be helpful for others in the future.